# Searching for a string in a String-Array item element

Tags: android

How to search for a specific text inside a string-array item element? The following is an example of the xml file. The string-array name is android. I have some items inside the string-array. Now I want to do a search for the word "software". Please tell me how to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<string-array name="android">
    <item>Android is a software stack for mobile devices that includes an operating system, middleware and key applications.</item>
    <item>Google Inc. purchased the initial developer of the software, Android Inc., in 2005..</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume that you want to do this in code. There's nothing in the api to do text matching on an entire String array; you need to do it one element at a time:

```
String[] androidStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.android);
for (String s : androidStrings) {
    int i = s.indexOf("software");
    if (i >= 0) {
        // found a match to "software" at offset i
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use a Matcher and Pattern, or you could iterate through the array with an index if you wanted to know the position in the array of a match. But this is the general approach.

Comment: But what if we have to search from a string in `strings.xml` file?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad - I'm not sure what the question means. Do you mean somehow specifying search logic inside a resource file? Android doesn't support that. If you mean searching in Java code all the strings declared in `strings.xml`, Android doesn't support that, either, since the file name for string resources is discarded by the resource compiler. You could perhaps use reflection to search through all string resources by iterating through the fields of `R.strings`, but I can't imagine a use case that would require that.

Comment: actually I am having 10 strings in strings.xml file and I have 10 `TextView`s to show them. I want to allow the user to search. Depending on his query, I want to highlight the word in the `TextView` if his search matches with the words in the string. How to do that? I just need some hint.

Answer (score 29):

This method has better performances:

```
String[] androidStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.android);   
if (Arrays.asList(androidStrings).contains("software") {
    // found a match to "software"           
}
```

`Arrays.asList().contains()` is faster than using a `for` loop.

Comment: This will not do what OP wants, which (based on the examples posted) is to find elements of the list that _contain_ the word "software". This will only find elements that are _equal_ (in their entirety) to the word "software". Also, `List.contains` uses a loop internally; it is no faster than using a loop in your own code. Plus you have the added overhead of creating a `List` wrapper around the `String[]`.