# How to equal some special words in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to show a Toast when EditText equals some special words. I know how to equal text but I want to equal 10 words may be more.

What is the best way to equal list of special words.

Comment: keep the words in an array and compare them one by one using a loop.

Comment: Better performances can be achieved by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16475338/2649012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to add all your words in array list that can grow dynamically, for example;

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(word1);
list.add(etc);
if(words.contains(editText.getText())){
//do something
}
```

I am not sure if that what you're looking for. Please add more details if that does not help you