# How to search a string value in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, search

I have an array with string in Android Studio, I want to search value, the values are with article and space how can I find. I want to search "das Buch"
It shouldn't pay attention to the capital or small letter

that is my Array :

```
public String myArray []= {"Das Buch","Die Fahne","Das Arbeitsbuch"};
```

I want to search for **fahne** and it should show me **die Fahne**

this is my code :

```
myText = editText.getText().toString();       

if (Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(myText)){
    Toast.makeText(this, myText + " found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, myText + " not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This is a common problem, and should already have solutions on this site. Please go through them, and update your question with code that you have tried. Also, this has nothing to do with android-studio, so please add appropriate tags.

Comment: String myArray []= {"das Buch","Die Fahne","Das Arbeitsbuch"};
        for(String s : myArray)
            if(s.toString().toLowerCase().contains("das"))
                Log.e("String found ", s);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for a string in a String-Array item element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501245/searching-for-a-string-in-a-string-array-item-element)

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct programming language

Comment: Hello Reza, welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is most likely going to get closed by the moderators for it's truly something you can find by searching (see the possible duplicate to get a potential answer that would help you). In any case, don't let this discourage you from posting future questions, we're all here to learn and to help where we can. In the future, it helps if you describe more what you have actually tried and what results you're getting that don't match your expectations.

Comment: @skillsmuggler i have seen that by it doesnt work . lowercase or upper case is important here. my array is upper case but my search is in lower case and it cant find it

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Somebody downvoted your question. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, you can do something like this with array element containing a String, with case insensitive comparison again using a common library, and then returning the list if need all elements in list containing the searched element:

```
String myArray[] = {"Das Buch", "Die Fahne", "Das Arbeitsbuch"};
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(myArray).stream()
                .filter(x -> org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(x, "das")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```